# Is Intel ESRT2 Software-RAID?

Tags: raid, software-raid, hardware-raid, intel-rst

I have 2 options for configuring RAID at the UEFI level. Intel ESRT 2 and Intel VROC which is the successor to Intel RST (rapid start).

I know Intel RST and thus VROC (which is present on non server broad) is definitely software RAID. It is recognized under Linux using mainline drivers under the kernel device mapper and in Windows speed was capped at 12Mb/s because of the limit of using a CPU core at 100%.

But does it mean that if I bother installing the out of tree drivers for Intel ESRT2 that it is an hardware accelerated RAID system just because its the opposed alternative to Intel VROC?